# Convert a list of bytes to a string in Python 3

Tags: python, string, byte

I'm writing a program in Python 3.4.1 that uses PySerial to test some hardware.

Bytes are read from the serial port one at a time, and then appended to list. When the list reaches a certain size, it is sent for processing.
Depending on the incoming data, the data sometimes has to be processed before the list is full, hence byte-by-byte operation.

The list then comes back as:

```
[b'F', b'o', b'o']
```

For part of the test script, I need to be able to convert this to a string, so that I can just print:

```
Foo
```

My solution is:

```
b''.join([b'F', b'o', b'o']).decode("ascii")
```

But it just feels wrong. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: no, there is no better approach. You need to join, and you need to decode. That's just life.

Comment: It's short, readable, and I'm sure you have no performance issue (it's a serial port..). Just move on.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, this is slightly more readable, but I wouldn't complain if I came across your code in review. Tested in Python 2.7:

```
>>> bytearray([b'F', b'o', b'o']).decode('ascii')
u'Foo'
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't work under 3.4.1. I get: TypeError: an integer is required.

Comment: Ah. I think what you have is best then.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like how `join` looks, you can do following:

```
bytes.join(b'', [b'F', b'o', b'o']).decode('ascii')
```

It's almost the same thing as in your code. I don't think you'll find any better approach.